# Nested set tree view data structure using with recursing and traversal techniques in MongoDB or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, tree, nested-sets

Hey I'm trying to implement nested drag&drop within re-order sequencesin my **MERN app**. I working to find ideal approach for mongodb data model and implement to `Lexicographic order` or `linked lists`  for infinite sub folders. I used [Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) in this link but every node have limitless children for that require recursion and recursive functions or currying. Documentations not clear enough for make do that.

I want show all tree once and not sohuld appear after than click to arrow icon.There is my doodles for front side generation that working with only one `depth` such like `graph nodes`. Maybe `Modified Preorder Tree Traversal`  implementation examples you have for this scenario.

```js
const tree = data => {  // immutable array
    let ascendants = data.filter(d=>d.parent==null)
    let descandants = data.filter(d=>d.parent)
  **strong text**
    let form = []
    ascendants.map(a=>{
        let node1 = {...a}; /// copying
            
            let node1Children = []; 
            descandants.map(b=>{
                let node2 = {...b};
                
                if(node1._id == b.parent){
                     node1Children.push(node2)
                }
                
            })

        node1.children = node1Children;


        form.push(node1);
    })
    return form;


}
```

I cant take result with using `$graphLookup`  because list format is not what i want.Could you give me some `mongodb playground` or grouping `aggregate`  solutions? Below json examples shown my expecting results. I can do before but hardcode is unapropriate and performless. Is comparing good way?

```js
[
    // mongo database
    {_id:123, title:'Books', slug:'books', parent:null },
    {_id:124, title:'Programming', slug:'programming', parent:null },
    {_id:125, title:'JavaScript', slug:'javascript', parent:'programming' },
    {_id:126, title:'C++',slug:'cpp', parent:'programming' },
    {_id:127, title:'React', slug:'react', parent:'javascript' },
    {_id:128, title:'Redux', slug:'redux', parent:'react' },
    {_id:129, title:'Toolkit', parent:'redux' },
    {_id:130, title:'Saga', parent:'redux' },
    {_id:131, title:'Nodejs', parent:'programming' },
    {_id:132, title:'Databases', slug:'databases' },
    {_id:133, title:'MongoDB', parent:'databases' },
]

[
   // what i want
   { title: "Books"},
   { title: "Programming", parent:"computer-science", children: [

        { title: "JavaScript", children: [
            { title: "React",  children: [
                { title: "Redux", children: [
                    { title: "Saga" },
                    { title: "Thunk" },
                    { title: "Mobx" },
                    { title: "Observable" },
                    { title: "Context" },
                    { title: "GraphQL" },
                    { title: "Toolkit", children:[
                        { title: "typescript" },
                        { title: "slices", children:[
                            { title: "createAsyncThunk" },
                            { title: "createSlice" },
                        ] },
                   ] },

                ] },
                { title: "Nextjs" },
            ]},
            { title: "Vue", },
            { title: "angular", },

        ]},
        { title: "C++", },
        { title: "NodeJS", },

   ] },
   { title: "MongoDB", parent: "databases"},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Map to key your objects by `slug`. The values per key will be the result objects for parent objects. Include an entry for `null`, which will collect the top-level elements.

Then iterate the data again to populate `children` arrays -- when that property does not exist yet, create it on the fly. Finally output the top-level elements.

```js
function makeTree(data) {
    let children = []; // Top-level elements
    let map = new Map(data.map(({title, slug}) => [slug, { title }]))
                     .set(null, {children});
    for (let {slug, parent, title} of data) {
        (map.get(parent || null).children ??= [])
                .push(slug ? map.get(slug) : {title});
    }
    return children;
}

// Your mongodb data:
const data = [{_id:123, title:'Books', slug:'books', parent:null },{_id:124, title:'Programming', slug:'programming', parent:null },{_id:125, title:'JavaScript', slug:'javascript', parent:'programming' },{_id:126, title:'C++',slug:'cpp', parent:'programming' },{_id:127, title:'React', slug:'react', parent:'javascript' },{_id:128, title:'Redux', slug:'redux', parent:'react' },{_id:129, title:'Toolkit', parent:'redux' },{_id:130, title:'Saga', parent:'redux' },{_id:131, title:'Nodejs', parent:'programming' },{_id:132, title:'Databases', slug:'databases' },{_id:133, title:'MongoDB', parent:'databases' }];

console.log(makeTree(data));
```